The principal clause lacking helping verb

There were chickens, pigeons and legs of mutton in the roast and an appetizing odor of roast, beef. Leaf and gravy dripping over the browned skin, which increased the appetite and made everybody's mouth water.

a. In the first sentence,there is a comma after the word 'beef'. What is it's reason? Is there any other sense of the sentence if we remove comma?
b. Leaf and gravy is the main clause of the sentence that is missing the helping verb 'was' which should have been there to support the main verb 'dripping'. In the absence of this helping verb, the whole sentence seems ungrammatical. Furthermore, the verb 'dripping' appears nonsensical in reference to leaf.

Where did you find this sentence? I see a comma before the word 'beef', which to my mind should be omitted. I don't understand the meaning of 'leaf' in this context.

The OP has correctly spotted the abnormalities in the example:

*... an appetizing odor of roast, beef. Leaf and gravy dripping over the browned skin, which increased the appetite ...

The comma between roast and beef should be either deleted or replaced with and.
The verb BE is indeed missing before dripping.
The OP's comment about the leaf dripping seems valid.  With leaf deleted, we use was, gravy was dripping.
